# The RecurringApplicationCharge refund policy for unstalled application

Tags: api, rest, shopify

In the case when the shop has the `RecurringApplicationCharge` for example with a 30-day recurring charge. The `RecurringApplicationCharge` was created on for example August 01, and the application was removed on August 15.

As I understood from Shopify documentation, Shopify platform will automatically remove the  `RecurringApplicationCharge`, but what happened with the refund? Does the Shopify automatically refund for the not used days? Or this part is the responsibility of the application owner?

Any information will be helpful I'm trying to find some clear description/documentation what exactly happens after the application was uninstalled.

Application using the latest Shopify REST API ([https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/billing/recurringapplicationcharge?api[version]=2020-07](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/billing/recurringapplicationcharge?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-07)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Uninstalling apps with recurring charges

Make sure that you consider app billing cycles when you plan to uninstall an app. Recurring app charges are generated the first time an app charge is approved, and then on the first day of an app's billing cycle. Because of this, a charge will appear on your bill even if you uninstall an app only a day or two after you install it.

Shopify themselves will not refund the amount. There is no procedure for the same. Me being an APP creater has faced the same issue. The only way here is the App creator pays the amount back to the merchant if they decide to Uninstall the App.

Here are few documentations that may help you understand better:
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/your-account/manage-billing/your-invoice/apps
https://shopify.dev/tutorials/charging-for-your-app-with-rest-admin-api-concepts